# css calc() не работает

Tags: html, css

Подскажите где ошибка в выражении

```
height: calc(100% * 472px / 100);
```

Ищу пропорцию, где-то ошибаюсь

Comment: При `*` один из аргументов должен быть числом (без размерности), при `/` справа от дроби должно быть число без размерности. Справка на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Answer (score 1):

Нельзя умножать проценты на пиксели - это совершенно бессмысленная операция.

Кстати, к сожалению, делить тоже нельзя - таков уж стандарт css.